# How many volume groups can be created in physical volume?

Tags: lvm

I want to know the details regarding LVM: please provide some link regarding Linux to study and understand it.

Answer (score 3):

The best resources are `man` pages. To answer your question, see `man vgcreate`

> -l, --maxlogicalvolumes MaxLogicalVolumes
>               Sets the maximum number of logical volumes allowed in this volume group.  The setting can be changed with  vgchange(8).   For  volume  groups
>               with  metadata  in  lvm1  format, the limit and default value is 255.  If the metadata uses lvm2 format, the default value is 0 which removes
>               this restriction: there is then no limit.

You should also read the man pages for `pvcreate` and `lvcreate` for a fuller understanding of logical volumes and `man lvm` for the overview.