# Multiple Logical volumes on Volume group

Tags: linux, debian, rhel, lvm

I am trying to create multiple logical volumes (more than 2000) on volume group. In this process, I have seen that "lvcreate" command will fail to create logical volume with message "metadata too large for circular buffer".

On googling, I understood that this is due to insufficient "pvmetadatasize" value on each disk which are part of volume group.

I am interested in understanding the relation between the value of pvmetadatasize and the count of logical volumes which can be created.

Is there any command output from which I can sense the above info OR any command to monitor pvmetadatasize ?

Comment: Check this one https://superuser.com/questions/896700/get-current-metadatasize-for-an-physical-volume

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150505/how-many-volume-groups-can-be-created-in-physical-volume

Comment: Though the volume group has sufficient memory, with my experiments I have seen that lvcreate fails due to insufficient metadata information.
I was wondering if there is any mechanism from which I can determine how much metadata I should allocate using pvcreate so that my maximum number of logical volumes are created.